# How do I get Json array element one by one by jquery on different id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

This is my JSON data:

```
[{
    "date": "28-06-2015",
    "title": "PAPER",
    "description": "For more Detail Click here</a>"
},
{
    "date": "27-06-2015",
    "title": "PAPER",
    "description": "For more Detail Click here</a>"
},
{
    "date": "25-06-2015",
    "title": "PAPER",
    "description": "For more Detail Click here</a>"
}]
```

I need data on different id's. I don't know how to loop through this data and get one by one

Comment: It's an array, so you can loop using any standard JS convention, such as `for`, `while` etc.

Comment: function fetchfromJsonfile(){ 
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
url: "URL_HERE",
cache: false,
beforeSend: function() {
$('#res2').html('loading please wait...');
},
success: function(jsondata) {  
var str = '';
str += '<ul>';
$.each(jsondata, function(idx, obj) {   
str += '<li>' + obj.cdate + ' - ' + obj.ctitle + ' - ' + obj.desciption+ '</li>';
});
str += '</ul>';
$('#res2').html(str);
}
});
} This is what I have done

Answer (score 1):

Use an each loop to parse your data with a loop

```
var data =  [
    {
        "date": "28-06-2015",
        "title": "PAPER",
        "description": "For more Detail Click here</a>"
    },
    {
        "date": "27-06-2015",
        "title": "PAPER",
        "description": "For more Detail Click here</a>"
    },
    {
        "date": "25-06-2015",
        "title": "PAPER",
        "description": "For more Detail Click here</a>"
    }
];


$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    console ("for this id: " + i + ", I have this data: " + data[i]);
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function iterateJsonArray(jsonArray){
  for(i in jsonArray){
      console.log(jsonArray[i]);        
   }
}
```

Call this

```
    var r = [
    {
        "date": "28-06-2015",
        "title": "PAPER",
        "description": "For more Detail Click here</a>"
    },
    {
        "date": "27-06-2015",
        "title": "PAPER",
        "description": "For more Detail Click here</a>"
    },
    {
        "date": "25-06-2015",
        "title": "PAPER",
        "description": "For more Detail Click here</a>"
    }
];

iterateJsonArray(r);
```

Comment: A comment with a downvote is recommended by the ethics of StackOverflow.